# using a delphi callback function in a C dll

Tags: c, delphi, dll, callback

I'm using a C dll in a Delphi XE2 program without problem. One of the DLL function takes a function as argument.

Here is the prototype of the function:

```
var
 LMX_MySetOption: function(LmxHandle: LMX_HANDLE;
                             eOption: _LMX_SETTINGS;
                            callback: TCallBackProcedure): LMX_STATUS cdecl 
                                                {$IFDEF WIN32} stdcall {$ENDIF};
```

The original prototype in C of the function was:

```
LMX_STATUS LMX_SetOption(LMX_HANDLE LmxHandle, LMX_SETTINGS eOption, 
                                               const void *pSetting);
```

TCallBackProcedure is defined as follow:

```
type
 TCallBackProcedure = procedure(bla : Pointer) stdcall;
```

I'm calling the function this way:

```
LMX_MySetOption(LmxHandle, LMX_OPT_HEARTBEAT_EXIT_FUNCTION, UserExitRoutine);
```

The UserExitRoutine is definede as follow:

```
procedure UserExitRoutine(bla : Pointer) stdcall;
begin
...
end;
```

It's not working (access violation)
I can't modify the C dll.

Many thanks for any idea!

Comment: `TCallbackProcedure` and `const void *pSetting` don't seem to me to match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If is a C procedure don't use stdcall use cdecl .

And you can simply declare this

```
 function LMX_MySetOption(LmxHandle: LMX_HANDLE;
                             eOption: _LMX_SETTINGS;
                            callback: Pointer): LMX_STATUS;cdecl;external 'yourmodule.dll'; 

procedure callback(bla:Pointer);cdecl;
begin
   //Some code
end;

LMX_MySetOption(LmxHandle, LMX_OPT_HEARTBEAT_EXIT_FUNCTION, @callback);
```

It should work...if it doesn't maybe you don't know the exact nr of parameters that the function has...

Comment: Thanks but it's not working. The signature of the callback function is declared like that in the original C header file: `typedef void (LMX_CALLBACK *HeartbeatExit_pfn)(void *pVendorData);`. LMX_CALLBACK is defined as `__stdcall` if _WIN32 is defined.

Comment: Maybe pVendorData references a structure that requires additional bytes and tryes to write a region of memory witch is not commited...another explanation i don't have for you.

Comment: Many Thanks, in fact it's working, it's just the dll who didn't called the callback when I was expected it!